# TextArea Value Undo Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textarea

I am making my own markdown editor, and so far, everything is going as planned.

It adds **strong** *italic* etc when corresponding buttons are pressed.

However, the browser `cmd+z` is broken because the functions called are changing the value of the textarea.

Is there a way so that the undo, redo works like the markdown editor for stackoverflow?

Would I have to save the values of textarea and have it undo and redo?

Comment: A textarea generally has that functionality built in by default, how exactly is it broken ?

Comment: @adeneo I am making a markdown editor, so for example, pressing the `bold button` will add `**placeholder**`. I can't undo such functionalities because it plays with the `textarea.value`.